# Examples of Design Patterns used in JDK

Tags: design-patterns, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Examples of GoF Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

At an interview a while back I was asked for some examples of Design Patterns within the JDK.

Off the top of my head I was able to identify

Flyweight - as used in the String pool
Singleton - in java.lang.Runtime
Iterator - as used on Collections classes

Not that many.

What are the other good examples of Design Patterns as used in the JDK?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns

Comment: Factory Factory Factory - http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431

Comment: Already asked with 500+ votes up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Observer** interfaces, you have them out-of-the-box.

For a complete answer, read this: [Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Answer (score 5):

Ouch, that's a tough question. Patterns are used almost everywhere in java. You can find some patterns used in Java EE on the Java BluePrints page.

---

**Resources :**

- [Java BluePrints](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/blueprints-141945.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can try a straightforward approach: goto the [JDK Javadoc](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) and search for (`Ctrl + F`) the names of some design patterns. For example,

- [Factory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicIconFactory.html)
- [Observer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html) & [Observable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)
- [Visitor](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/AbstractAnnotationValueVisitor6.html)